# Quotation marks in notepad++ won't allow text to transfer to html

Tags: double-quotes

My problem is I write a simple code in notepad++ ex.

```
<p><input type=Submit value="Click here!"></p>
```

So "click here!" will turn purple and not show up on the web page.

I seem to have no issue if I do not use the quotation marks, but I figure I need to as that is best practice?

I hope I am not too vague. If needed I can supply a screenshot. I'm new to coding so I want to make sure I get all aspects of it.

Comment: Please provide the code, by copying it into the post, and not in a screenshot. You can post a screenshot of the problem, but please also include the code directly into your post

Comment: Please post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After playing around and looking in a million places, it was some default settings I had not looked at yet. I appreciate any help offered and next time I'll make sure to post code and whatever else is needed. Thanks again!